# Unable to convert notebook file (.ipynb) into pdf

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am converting  jupyetr notebook to pdf, but unable to do it. Am able to convert a simple notebook file into pdf . The current file has many markdown cells and am unable to convert it into pdf.  I have used nbconvert too, but it didn't work out.
Even the html file is not generated properly

The notebook code is below

```
[text](https://indiannational-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/k_nunna-p_incois_gov_in/EWNKbXZQ5SNIlpSoR3U30tkBCcw9A3VYMGB_NAwCdBq7JQ?e=ZjfL1w)
```

I request, anyone to guide me on this, as i need to generate the report..
Thanking you,
kameshwari

I tried nbconvert, but didnt work out